# Auth on ngrok event not found

Tags: command-line, ngrok

I'm trying to auth on ngrok:

```
aaas-iMac:sss aaa$ ~/ngrok -authtoken bbtw942UevV!Ap94JzFz 80
-bash: !Ap94JzFz: event not found
```

What's with this? How do I auth? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token has an un-escaped exclamation mark (`!`) in it, which is being interpreted by `bash` as a command [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

You need to escape it by enclosing the authtoken in single quotes:

```
$ ~/ngrok -authtoken 'bbtw942UevV!Ap94JzFz' 80
```

Alternatively, escape it with a slash:

```
$ ~/ngrok -authtoken bbtw942UevV\!Ap94JzFz 80
```